Docker sharp installation error on M3 Macbook
I'm having problems with a Docker project, which started correctly on my old Intel Macbook Pro.
Basically I have a backend service developed with Node 14.15.1 on 4 different containers.

As you can see I use Mac version of Docker Desktop 4.30.0
When I launch the containers, the 'hfs_platform' container returns the following error in the installation:
2024-05-20 18:03:35 yarn run v1.22.5
2024-05-20 18:03:35 $ yarn && yarn start
2024-05-20 18:03:35 [1/4] Resolving packages...
2024-05-20 18:03:36 [2/4] Fetching packages...
2024-05-20 18:04:12 info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
2024-05-20 18:04:12 info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2024-05-20 18:04:12 info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
2024-05-20 18:04:12 info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2024-05-20 18:04:12 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
2024-05-20 18:04:19 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
2024-05-20 18:04:20 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
2024-05-20 18:04:22 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2024-05-20 18:03:35 warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > @neutrinojs/airbnb-base@9.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning "@neutrinojs/airbnb-base > @neutrinojs/eslint@9.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning "@neutrinojs/airbnb-base > @neutrinojs/eslint > eslint-loader@4.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties > @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > @babel/preset-typescript@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning "@babel/preset-typescript > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning "@babel/preset-typescript > @babel/plugin-transform-typescript > @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > ttypescript@1.5.15" has unmet peer dependency "ts-node@>=8.0.2".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > @neutrinojs/library@9.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > @neutrinojs/library@9.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack-cli@^3.0.0".
2024-05-20 18:04:12 warning " > eslint-import-resolver-typescript@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@*".
2024-05-20 18:04:20 error /srv/app/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
2024-05-20 18:04:20 Exit code: 1
2024-05-20 18:04:20 Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
2024-05-20 18:04:20 Arguments: 
2024-05-20 18:04:20 Directory: /srv/app/node_modules/sharp
2024-05-20 18:04:20 Output:
2024-05-20 18:04:20 sharp: Installation error: Use with glibc 2.24 requires manual installation of libvips >= 8.11.3
2024-05-20 18:04:20 sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
2024-05-20 18:04:22 error Command failed with exit code 1.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.7'

services:
  sql:
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
    container_name: hfs_sql
    image: library/mysql:8.0.22
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - hfs-network
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    volumes:
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:rw
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=hfs
      - MYSQL_USER=hfs
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=hfs
    ports:
      - '3003:3306'

  adminer:
    container_name: hfs_adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - sql
    networks:
      - hfs-network
    ports:
      - '8999:8080'

  platform:
    container_name: hfs_platform
    image: library/node:14.15.1
    command: yarn start:container
    working_dir: /srv/app
    networks:
      - hfs-network
    depends_on:
      - sql
    volumes:
      - /srv/app/node_modules
      - ../:/srv/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '9229:9229'

  nginx:
    container_name: hfs_nginx
    image: nginx:1.17.10
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - platform
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    networks:
      - hfs-network
    volumes:
      - ../src/resources/assets:/var/www/html
      - ./certs:/etc/ssl/certs
      - ./dhparam:/etc/ssl/dhparam
      - ./configs/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro

networks:
  hfs-network:
    driver: bridge

And this is my dockerfile also:
FROM node:14.18.2-bullseye-slim

COPY ./package.json /srv
COPY ./tsconfig.json /srv
COPY ./yarn.lock /srv
COPY ./src /srv/src

WORKDIR /srv

RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

CMD [ "yarn", "execute" ]

The containers were running correctly before the computer change, so I imagine the situation depends on the new Apple chip.
Do you have any ideas about it? Thanks so much for the help.
I looked at the documentation as written at the link https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install and in the various official repositories without finding the solution

FROM node:14.18.2-bullseye-slim is so old, I'm surprised that's the only error you got. The old still in support version of Node is the v18 maintenance LTS version, with the current active LTS being Node 20.

I know it, but I can't update node version utill this september and I search a fix for it

Then you're going to have to do what the error tells you to do, because that docker image is too old. The OS it's built on top of comes with versions of required libraries that are simply too old.

Ok, but i don't understand how can install libvips on my docker image manually

So downgrade your version of Sharp to whichever existed when Node 14 was the LTS version, so you don't run into "using too modern a dependency with a dead version of Node/the OS you're using".

Thank you sir, I'll give you back feedback soon

I solved this problem upgrading sharp library, wich support yet node >= 12 and new arm Apple chip
